# DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'structuredClone' on 'Window': Symbol(react.element) could not be cloned

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make use of the structuredClone() function inside my react app.
its working in ubuntu but not in windows.

```
flightnewDatas.push(structuredClone({ ...reslgs, traveller: travellerData, seatData: travandSeat, seatArray: reslgs?.seatArray ? reslgs?.seatArray : [], noOfSeatsSelected: 0 }))
```

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(flightnewDatas))
```

```
const data = structuredClone(toRaw(flightnewDatas));
```

Comment: Which browser do you use on Ubuntu? Could you try to type `structuredClone(Symbol("foo"))` in your console? That should throw. That it doesn't means that either when ran on your Ubuntu config, the data doesn't contain that `Symbol`, either your browser has a bad bug they should fix.